# Communication between processes (main) Java

Tags: java, concurrency, process, parallel-processing, program-entry-point

I need to communicating various processes as it follows:

First I invoke GeneralMain with args[0] = 1, so it will call A.main().

The two remaining processes will launch in a space of random time, but both processes need to start at the same time.

My code:

```
public class GeneralMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num_proc = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        switch (num_proc) {
            case 1:
                A.main(...);
                break;

        case 2:
            B.main(...);
            break;

            case 3:
                C.main(...);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

First the GeneralMain recieve args[0] = 1, and calls **A.main();**.

So, I execute the GeneralMain for three times. In the first time A.main() is started and is the responsible of recieve messages, Then I execute GeneralMain that start B.main() process and send the first message to A. To end, I execute GeneralMain that start C.main() process and send the second message to A, but I need that B.main() and C.main() starts at the same time and send his message at the same time

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear, are you facing an error?

Comment: Im spanish so its difficult for me to express the problem :'(

Comment: Yes. So, I execute the GeneralMain for three times. In the first time A.main() is started and is the responsible of recieve messages, Then I execute GeneralMain that start B.main() process and send the first message. To end, I execute GeneralMain that start C.main() process and send the second message, but I need that B.main() and C.main() starts at the same time and send his message at the same time

Comment: Why do B and C need to be started at exactly the same time?

Comment: I need to prove that interlaced different executions
produce different results. A.main() shows the last recieved message,

Answer (score 0):

You might look at using threads and runnable's.

From main you could start A then start 2 threads using a random time at which they would both start. One thread calls B and the other calls C.

Comment: Yes I know this solution, but I cant automatize it. Must start B and C manually

Comment: I suppose when we are talking "at the same time" we are looking at human time not computer time. This being the case you could stick with your original code and use a batch script to start B and C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cyclic barrier to make sure B and C start executing their logic at the same time.

```
CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(2); //global scope

B { //thread B's main
    cyclicBarrier.await(); //wait for other thread
}
C { //thread C's main
    cyclicBarrier.await(); //wait for other thread
}
```

Basically both B and C will register themselves at the barrier and as soon as the registered parties number reaches 2 the barrier will trip and B and C will start executing their logic at more or less the same time (not sure how exact the synchronization is)